# Математика. Определитель матрицы n-го порядка

Tags: математика, матрицы, math

[image: Вычислить определитель матрицы n-го порядка]

Помогите с задачей, не могу до конца додумать, что куда и как. Спасибо большое заранее!

Для начала я попытался изменить вторую строчку с помощью первой, у меня вышло:

```
x   x+h   x+2h  ...  x+(n-1)h
0   2x+h  x+2h  ...  x+(n-1)h
0   -x     x    ...     0
.............................
0    0     0    ...     x
```

Если здесь что-то ещё менять то, -x из 3ей строчки не уходит, а я хочу привести матрицу к виду:

```
x x x x
0 x x x
0 0 x x
0 0 0 x
```

Чтобы можно было разложить на миноры по 1 эл-ту.

Далее я попытался вторую оставить без изменения, а 3ью строчку изменить с помощью первой, но там тоже получилась белиберда и далекая к истине матрица. Я думал может можно при помощи какого-нибудь столбца изменить другой, но тем самым больше проблем создам.

В принципе тут ещё одна идея - изменять вторую с помощью первой, третью с помощью второй и т.д., а потом выносить из каждой строчки множитель (x+h), но остаются единицы и нужному виду не придти. :(
[image: Определители]

Comment: Если вы попытались сами решить, дополните вопрос, если нет, я голосую за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: Хорошо, всё написал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если я не ошибся...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update**
Доказывается методом матиндукции. Для каких-нибудь 1, 2, 3 - легко посчитать.

Затем берем nxn и идем по последнему столбцу. Имеем минор для (x+nh) - получается простая матрица с одной диагональю из (-x)<sup>n</sup>, а для x в нижнем правом углу - наша формула для n. Умножаем, суммируем - все получается как надо :)

**Update2**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо больше за ответ! А можно ход действий, просто алгоритм рассуждения.

Comment: Да просто прикинул несколько первых - очень простой и красивый ряд получился... Не делал, но, как мне кажется, матиндукцией должно легко доказываться. Дописываем одну строку и столбец справа - и вперед по минорам...

Comment: а разве можно дописывать в конце ещё один столбик?

Comment: Столбик справа и нижнюю строку, само собой. Просто миноры брать не по строке, а по столбику. Понимаете, я бы мог это изложить, но как представлю, сколько набирать в TeX'е - мне становится плохо... :(

Comment: Посмотрите изображение, насчёт первого определителя понятно, а вот второй, где через x, основная задача найти его, вся загвостка сводится опять к его решению.

Comment: А второй - мы и берем нашу уже известную формулу как гипотезу (см. мои каракули). Идея матиндукции в чем? У нас есть формула, которую надо доказать. Мы убеждаемся в ее справледивости для какого-то n, типа, 1, 2 - а потом доказываем, что *если она верна для n, то она верна и для n+1*. Тогда она верна для любых n. Вот я и использую для поиска определителя для n+1 мою формулу для n, и получаю точно такую же, где n заменено на n+1. Значит, формула верна :)

Comment: Ладно, спасибо большое! Основная идея и была найти эту формулу :) А в методе матиндукции мы от нее двигаемся, всё равно спасибо большое за старания и потраченное на меня время!

Comment: Только у вас при (-1) степень должна быть 1+(n+1) - потому что столбец последний уже n+1-й.

Comment: Ну, а найти - так даже Грэхем с Кнутом не гнушаются методом посмотреть первые несколько членов - см. "Конкретную математику". Это вполне корректный метод с точки зрения математиков :)

Comment: Я просто только на первом курсе:) Мы ещё изучаем просто определители на алгебре.

Comment: А метод матиндукции уже знаете? Не скажу точно, но по воспоминаниям советского времени его основы чтоб еще не в 10 классе давали...

Comment: Да, мы его первым делом прошли, даже на всех дисциплинах: мат. анализ, алгебра, аналитическая геометрия и введение в инж. деятельность.

Comment: Все, тогда этот метод, которым я воспользовался, совершенно корректен и не выходит за рамки начитанного вам материала :)

Comment: Отлично. Уже скачал книгу Конкретной математики, в скором времени начну познавать все её прелести. Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: Она того стоит :) Какое издание нашли? рекомендую 2010 года, от "Вильямса".

Comment: "Мир" 1998 под редакцией А.Б.Ходулёва